# Quota limit for autoConvertMissingPrices in Google Play Developer API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-developers-console, quota

I got problems with [v3/inappproducts/patch](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/patch) method

It has a query parameter - `autoConvertMissingPrices`

> If true the prices for all regions targeted by the parent app that don't have a price specified for this in-app product will be auto converted to the target currency based on the default price. Defaults to false.

The documentation does not state this anywhere, but it turned out that there is a daily quota for using this parameter.
I don't know the exact limit, but it's not enough for me. I need to change this quota or request a quota increase, but, in the Google Console, I didn’t even find anything close to that.

The error I get in response is: `Daily missing prices autoconversion quota exceeded.`

Google itself knows nothing about this error...

I looked in the API documentation. Was looking for a quota setting in Google Console. I asked ChatGPT.
I didn't find any information about this problem anywhere.

up.